# Zend session seems to be restarted on each page load

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've been having a lot of trouble trying to get Zend sessions to work properly. Basically, what I need to do is set a variable once when the site loads. This variable should then remain constant throughout the lifetime of the session.

To help make this a little more clear, let's take the following scenario:

In Bootstap.php, I have

```
protected function _initSession() {
    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
    $session->testValue = rand(0, 100);
}
```

Then, I access it elsewhere in the application as follows:

```
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
echo $session->testValue;
```

Now what I'd hope is that $session->testValue would be assigned once, and that value would be the same on every subsequent page request. But in reality, what's happening is that $session->testValue is a new random number each time.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Every time Bootstrap.php is run it's overwriting the testValue property. Only set it if it hasn't been set yet.

```
protected function _initSession() {
    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
    if (!isset($session->testValue)) {
        $session->testValue = rand(0, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought as much myself, but if I do that, I get a new random value each time I refresh the page.

Comment: If it makes any difference, sessions are being stored on the filesystem, not in a cookie

Comment: You've verified that the session files are being generated?

Comment: Yes. I can refresh the page and watch a new file be put in the directory.